# If $a,b\in R$ and $a \neq 0$ and quadratic $ax^2-bx+c=0$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, complex-numbers

If $a,b\in R$ and $a \neq 0$ and quadratic $ax^2-bx+c=0$ has imaginary roots  then  $a+b+1$
why a+b+1 should be positive?

Comment: Do you mean imaginary, or (non-real) _complex_ roots?

Comment: the book say imaginary

Comment: You get imaginary roots only if $b=0$.

Comment: $-2x^2-8=0$ has imaginary roots $\pm2i$ but $ a+b+1=-2+0+1=-1<0$.

Comment: Most responses so far assume that $c$ is real. But do we know that ? The question only says that $a$ and $b$ are real.

Answer (score 0):

The roots of $ax^2-bx+c$ are given by 
$$
\frac{b\pm\sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2},
$$
which are both complex if and only if $b^2-4ac<0$.